# Python string not formatting properly

Tags: python

I have this code

```
print("{0:<10} {1:>25}".format("Name", "RAM"))
    for droplet in droplets:
      print("{0:<10} {1:>25}".format(droplet.name, droplet.memory))
```

I want it to print out a nice column like this:

```
Name                             RAM
example-droplet                  1024
ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc1-01       1024
```

But instead I get this:

```
Name                             RAM
example-droplet                           1024
ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc1-01                           1024
```

How can I get my desired output?

Comment: You ask the first field to only be 10.  Should it be 25 instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You indent to the wrong side. Try this:

```
print("{0:<30}{1:<10}".format("Name", "RAM"))
for droplet in droplets:
    print("{0:<30}{1:<10}".format(droplet.name, droplet.memory))
```

which prints

```
Name                          RAM       
example-droplet               1024      
ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-ncy1-01    1024
```

for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can try as following

```
print("{0:35} {1}".format("Name", "RAM"))
for droplet in droplets:
    print("{0:35} {1}".format(droplet.name, droplet.memory))
```

*Testing by changing droplets to map*:

```
print("{0:35} {1}".format("Name", "RAM"))
droplets = [{'name': 'example-droplet', 'memory':1024}, {'name': 'ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc1-01', 'memory':256}]
for droplet in droplets:
    print("{0:35} {1}".format(droplet['name'], droplet['memory']))
```

Result:

```
Name                                RAM
example-droplet                     1024
ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc1-01          256
```

Comment: @eozd's answer is simpler but thank you for helping!